# Unable to scrape some URLs from a webpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all the restaurant URLs on a page.  There are only 5 restaurant URLs to scrape in this particular example.

At this stage, I am just trying to print them to see if my code works.  However, I am not even able to get that done: - my code is unable to find any of the URLs.

```
import scrapy

from hungryhouse.items import HungryhouseItem

class HungryhouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hungryhouse"
    allowed_domains = ["hungryhouse.co.uk"]

    start_urls = ["https://hungryhouse.co.uk/takeaways/westhill-ab32",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="restsRestInfo"]/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            print url
```

any guidance as to why the five URLs are not being found would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you sure that the xpath is correct? Maybe try a more basic xpath such as just a tags.

Comment: I think the xpath is correct - though to be honest I am not sure.

Comment: @nevster Your xpath is correct and the URLs seem to have been extracted worked correctly. Are you running your scrapers at loglevel DEBUG? can you share the command to run your spiders?

Comment: Oddly, it is now working for me as well - I don't really understand that unless for some reason the webpage was taking too long to load before.  The command I was using to run the spider was "scrapy crawl hungryhouse"